# Cannot set the keyboard type programmatically - ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface, uikeyboard

I am having trouble setting the UIKeyboardtype in my app.

These are the 2 lines that are not being reflected in my app.

```
_firstTextFieldWebsite.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
_firstTextFieldWebsite.keyboardType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

The code is found within this context. All the other customizations that you see work.

```
_firstTextFieldWebsite = [[UITextField alloc] init];
_firstTextFieldWebsite.frame = CGRectMake(20, 73, 280, 30);
_firstTextFieldWebsite.placeholder = @"Enter the url here";
_firstTextFieldWebsite.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
_firstTextFieldWebsite.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_firstTextFieldWebsite.delegate = self;
_firstTextFieldWebsite.alpha = 1.0;

//[_firstTextFieldWebsite setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeURL];

_firstTextFieldWebsite.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
_firstTextFieldWebsite.keyboardType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

[self.view addSubview:_firstTextFieldWebsite];
```

What I am I missing or doing wrong?
I am not using storyboard here and my app is based on an IOS 6 minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the keyboard type incorrectly. Use:

```
_firstTextFieldWebsite.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
_firstTextFieldWebsite.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

Comment: Thank you:-) I see now that I was overwriting the keyboardType twice:-) I'll accept in a few minutes when SO lets me.